# C# Selenium Chrome Driver isnt waiting

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

my ChromeDriver doesnt waits for imlicityWaits and only waits for ElementExists in ExplicitWaits all others throw Errors.
I cannot use other ExpectedConditions then ElementExits.

```
    public async Task LoginPage()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"https://www.google.de/");

            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            Console.WriteLine("10 Sec");

            new WebDriverWait(Globals.webDriverChrome.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//*[@id='gbqfbb']")));
            Console.WriteLine("Hahahahha i did the job");

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Nuget Fody/Costura add-in was the problem. Uninstalled, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check this element you are referring by ID, maybe it is loaded before.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Wait(int seconds)
        {
            DriverContext.Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);
            new WebDriverWait(DriverContext.Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds)).Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElement(DriverContext.Driver.FindElement(By.Id("MyAccountLink")), "My Account"));
        }
```

I have been using this function for myself, just find finding element by ID